# Web Services compartilhar em diferentes projetos

Tags: java, web-service, aplicação-web, restful

Tenho 2 projetos, usando RestFull Jersey:

- ProjetoX
- ProjetoY

E o módulo de **Usuario**, esse módulo é responsável por fazer GET, POST, REMOVE  para manipular as informações referentes a Usuario.

Esse módulo é compartilhado entre esses projetos.
Porém gravado em Tablespaces diferentes, mas com mesma estrutura de tabela.

Usamos o seguinte fluxo:

**UsuarioWebService** -> **UsuarioAppService** -> **UsuarioBean** -> **UsuarioDAO**

O problema é:

- Crio um terceiro projeto **ProjetoGlobal** para colocar essas camadas inclusive o **UsuarioWebService**
- Ou Crio um terceiro projeto apenas com as 3 ultimas camadas e um **UsuarioWebService** para o **ProjetoX** e outro para o **ProjetoY** ?

Preciso entender o que é melhor no ponto de vista técnico.

Comment: Jovem, primeira coisa: qual a linguagem? Clique em [edit] e adicione a tag da linguagem.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo que crie ou implemente na sua aplicação um servidor [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/). Isso vem dado muito certo em empresas grandes como o Google e o Facebook, além de dar uma possibilidade de crescimento muito maior na sua aplicação.

Caso esteja utilizando Java e decida fazer modificações em um dos seus projetos, recomendo a utilização do [Spring Security](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) e [Spring Security OAuth2](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/) para desenvolver dentro do projeto.

Caso decida criar um novo projeto utilize o [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), e se não souber bem o que fazer deixei um [guia de como criar um servidor OAuth com Spring](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/).

Recomendo também a leitura e aprofundamento dos seus conhecimentos no projeto [OAuth 2.0](http://oauth.net/2/) e implementação do [Spring Security](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) em ambos os seus projetos para que tudo funcione da melhor maneira possível.

Deixei alguns links no final da resposta que possivelmente irão te ajudar.

Espero ter ajudado. Abraço!

**Observação**

O [OAuth 2.0](http://oauth.net/2/) possui na sua documentação outras formas de implementação e não funciona somente em JAVA como posso ter deixado entender. Então, se estiver usando outra linguagem, basta analisar os exemplos disponíveis no [site oficial](http://oauth.net/2/).

**Links que podem te ajudar**

- [Spring Security](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/)
- [Spring Security OAuth](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/)
- [Site oficial do OAuth 2.0](http://oauth.net/2/)
- [Guia sobre como criar um servidor OAuth2](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/)
- [Projetos do Spring](https://spring.io/projects)

Answer (score 0):

O propósito da solução não está muito bem explicado.

Para esclarecer: O usuário a ser retorna na requisição abaixo (fictícia) seria o mesmo ou diferente?

```
GET http://projeto-x.meudominio.com/usuario/1
GET http://projeto-y.meudominio.com/usuario/1
```

Se for diferente, é provável que o domínio de usuário evolua de forma diferente nos projetos, dessa forma eu não reaproveitaria o código. Simplesmente são projetos distintos com códigos distintos. Exemplificando: se você colocasse um campo específico do projeto-x para o usuário e o mesmo fosse obrigatório, obrigatoriamente você teria que fazer a modificação e deploy no projeto-y, o que não faria nenhum sentido.

Se o retorno esperado fosse o mesmo, faz sentido reaproveitar a implementação (ou parte dela). O que é estranho, do ponto de vista de arquitetura, é dois projetos distintos fazer a mesma coisa para uma mesma entidade (leitura/escrita). Se o projeto-x e projeto-y utilizasse serviços de usuário, o mais indicado é que os serviços dessas projetos utilizem um "usuario-service.jar" em suas camadas de serviço.

[]´s

Answer (score -1):

jbueno, muito provavelmente ele está usando Java...

Jorge, você precisa explicar melhor a funcionalidade do módulo de usuários, isto pode influenciar muito na sua decisão.

Entretanto, eu aconselho você  a dar uma olhada no padrão de projetos DTO, o ideal seria você colocar o seu serviço isolado dos projetos X e Y e compartilhar apenas os DTOs.

Isto com uma visão superficial do seu problema.

Comment: Gustavo, o local de respostas só pode ser usado para postar respostas. Lembre-se [o Stack Overflow em Português não é um fórum](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/18246). Quando você tiver pontos de reputação suficientes, poderá [comentar em qualquer publicação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Até lá, aconselho a tentar responder respostas que não necessitem de mais informações do autor da pergunta. Você pode entender melhor o uso do site no [tour] e na [help], também pode ver [ask] e [answer]. Aliás, bem vindo ao [pt.so]!

Comment: Eu atualizei a descrição. Verifica se agora eu fui mais objetivo. Vlw